# React-redux hooks with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, redux, react-redux

I am using `react-redux` hook `useSelector` with TypeScript. Is there any support for static typing? Now I have to cast using `as` keyword.

```
interface User { age: number }

const selectUser = (state): User => state.user.detail

const MyComponent = () => {

    const user1 = useSelector(selectUser)
    user1.age = 'This is not number.' // No warning or error.

    const user2 = useSelector<User>(selectUser)
    user2.age = 'This is not number.' // No warning or error.

    const user3 = useSelector(selectUser) as User
    user3.age = 'This is not number.' // TS2339 error, but with casting.

}
```

Comment: Remember that the react-redux hooks are still in alpha phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useSelector` has two type parameters `<TState, TSelected>`, second parameter is type of selected value. So this is working:

```
const user = useSelector<TState, User>(selectUser)
```

Comment: What is `TState`?

Comment: TState should be type of state of whole store.